# why foldl is not short circuiting with andFn function?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold, thunk

My understanding is that `foldl` and `foldr` executes like :

`foldl f a [1..30]` => `(f (f (f ... (f a 1) 2) 3) ... 30)`

and

`foldr f a [1..30]` => `(f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (f ....(f 30 a)))))..)`

so.. `foldr (&&) False (repeat False)` can shortciruit as outermost `f` sees `(&&) False ((&&) False (....))` sees first argument as false and does not need to evaluate the second argument (which is a large thunk).

so what happens with

```
andFn :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
andFn _ False = False
andFn x True  = x
```

and

```
foldl andFn True (repeat False)  -- =>

-- (andFn (andFn ...(andFn True False) ... False) False)
--  ^^ outermost andFn
```

But this is taking forever.

I thought that `outermost andFn` would know that by pattern matching on second argument, the answer is `False`..

What else is happening here ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a larger difference between `foldr` and `foldl` than the order of the arguments to `andFn`.

```
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

Notice how `foldr` immediately transfers control to `f`: if `f` is lazy it can avoid the computation of `foldr f z xs`.

Instead, `foldl` transfers control to... `foldl`: the function `f` will only start being used when the base case is reached

```
foldl f z [] = z      -- z contains the chained f's, which NOW get evaluated
```

Hence `foldl f z infiniteList` will *always* diverge, no matter what `f` is: the whole `infiniteList` needs to be completely iterated over before any real computation happens. (Off topic: this is why, even when it works, `foldl` often has horrible performance, and `foldl'` is more used in practice.)

In particular, the posted example

```
foldl andFn True (repeat False)  -- =>
-- (andFn (andFn ...(andFn True False) ... False) False)
--  ^^ outermost andFn
```

is partly wrong. The "outermost `andFn`" would actually be the *last* one, i.e. the one related to the *last* element in `repeat False`. But there is no such a beast.